# Using CSS to set default font

Tags: css

I have a file (CSS/FontStyle.css) containing this code:

```
.courier {
font-family: courier;
}
```

and my .aspx file has this code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Tut1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Rtw.Tut1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="StatusLabel" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/FontStyle.css"/>

    <h2>Unsigned Vs Signed Integers</h2>
//lots of text is below here..
```

However the font remains in time new roman. I can use other .css files from the same folder find, not sure why this one doesn't work?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your output HTML code? Your webserver's configuration can alter the actual HTML that is served to the browser. More CSS may be included that you aren't aware of. Just do "View source" from within the browser.

Comment: For reference, it's typically bad form to have CSS classes with purely presentational names like "courier" or "red" or "span2".  It's not much better than sticking the styles directly in the HTML.  Sure, you get the flexibility to change the styles in one place later...except that you can't really do so (say, to use Lucida Console instead) without making the code lie.  Instead, apply the styles to some root element, or to all elements of a certain type, or figure out what that stuff semantically represents ("output" or "code", for example), and name the class after that.

Comment: The code is too long to show here. But you can view the webpage here:
http://reinventingthewheel.azurewebsites.net/About.aspx

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try changing

```
.courier {
font-family: courier;
}
```

to

```
* {
    font-family: courier;
  }
```

The reason is the same as what @koala_dev mentioned. The ".courier" makes it apply only to elements of the class "courier," and from the code that you show none of your content is labeled with that class name, so the font is not being applied.

The `*` selector, however, will apply the CSS font-family rule to the text of all elements.

Note that CSS uses a specificity priority, and if you have any other CSS selectors that apply to the same elements, but with a more specific identifier than `*`, then any font-family specified in those CSS rules will override the general rule specified by the `*` selector.

#### Update (this is considered a bad idea in CSS, but may help)

If you can't find what other CSS rule may be conflicting, then you can use the `!important` rule to override other rules (unless those other rules are also using it):

```
* { font-family: courier !important }
```

#### Warning

Using `!important` is considered bad practice, however, but is useful possibly in your case where the conflicting CSS rule seems to be lost and you just need something that works.

What `!important` does is interfere with CSS's usual "cascading" rules for priority. As an example, the `h2` element would have the font-family courier in the below exam, even though the usual result would be arial (because of the more specific selector). The more specific selector `h2` is overridden by the less specific selector `*` because the `*` rule has the `!important` predicate applied to it.

```
* { font-family: courier !important }
h2 { font-family: arial }
```

For more info, please read this except and continue reading at the link that follows:

> ... postscripting your CSS values with !important can be highly abused and
>   make for messy and hard to maintain CSS. The unfortunate typical use
>   case goes like this:
>
> 1. WHY IS MY FRAGGLE ROCKING CSS NOT WORKING?!?!
> 2. (use !important rule)
> 3. OK, now it's working
>
> Then the next guy comes along and tries to make new changes. He tries
>   to alter some existing CSS rules, but now his changes aren't behaving
>   how they should. He traces the issue back to the !important rules,
>   then has a choice. He can try and remove those and attempt to get
>   things back on track, or add some more of his own to fight them and
>   get his change done. Since he might not know exactly why those
>   !important rules were added in the first place, he might opt for the
>   second option for fear of breaking something somewhere else on the
>   site he's not aware of. And thus the vicious cycle starts.

Continue reading here: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: hmm that didn't work, and I've tried it on a page that is using no other style sheets to see if other style sheets were messing with it.

Comment: Yes, you must have other CSS that is messing with the font. PS It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/cookies/vWWba/

Comment: So weird, it's working now! I'm using the * and !important, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that we got this one solved, and thank you to every one else as well!

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but I would hardly call using `*` and `!important` solved... CSS specificity is a powerful and important aspect of writing and maintaining CSS. It's my humble suggestion, but do yourself a favor and get familiar with the basics of CSS specificity and a DOM inspector to help you troubleshoot future specificity issues! `!important` can cause hours of headaches if you rely on it instead of learning about specificity. There *will* be times that `!important` is a smart choice, but empower yourself, and learn how to figure that out.

Comment: @Shango: Agreed.  `* { font-family: courier !important; }` just makes it so *everything* is Courier, in a way that even `style` attributes on the element itself can't override.  In order to use a different font anywhere in the page, you have to use `!important` again.  And it just goes downhill from there.

Comment: @Shango: For the record, I resisted mentioning `!important` in my answer until others forced my hand, and I already warned against using `!important` in my edited answer, and I'm fully aware of CSS's cascading and specificity rules. I'm even aware that the name "cascading style sheets" is based on that very principle, and I've written server-side include software that uses the same "cascading" mechanisms. In my delivered code I have never used `!important`--not a single time, ever. And when auditing code, I see its use as a big sign of likely communication problems within a developer team.

Answer (score 7):

You CSS rule is for a class name `courier`, if you want to set the font as default for your page use

```
body {
    font-family: "courier";
}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It's still in times new roman.

Comment: @user2261573 did you wrap the font name in quotes?

Comment: @user2261573 do you have any other CSS files that may be overwriting this value?

Comment: Note, you do not need to wrap the font name in quotes unless the font name is multiple words.

Comment: @JosephMyers: Tables haven't been a problem for a while; that only happens in quirks mode anymore.

Comment: @pep for some fonts even multiple words work without quotes, given they are uppercase at exactly right places.

Answer (score 5):

Courier is Macintosh/Unix, whereas Courier New is Microsoft's version. I would try setting both, with a fallback just in case (which most consider good practice); you should replace:

```
.courier {
    font-family: courier;
}
```

with

```
body {
    font-family: "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
}
```

Remember, if your CSS isn't working properly, a DOM inspector (eg. Chrome Inspect or Firefox Firebug) will help troubleshoot—especially when you need to identify if something is getting overwritten.

Just my 2¢, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**A)** are you applying the courier class anywhere. If not, and dont want to, then use body as selection point it will affect all its children elements too.

**B)** There may be classes other than yours which may have other css rules. So putting `!important` like i have will make sure browser listen to this css rule.

```
body {
    font-family: courier !important;
}
```

Comment: Avoid `!important` if you can, though.  It's typically a rather hamfisted approach, and if you are already having specificity issues, it will usually just make them worse by requiring that you use it even more to override it in this one special place where you don't want it to apply.  Before long, you're in the same situation, but now you can't use `!important` anymore cause you're already using it everywhere.  :P

Comment: i agree but sometimes when you are like debugging someone else css it is so much easier to fix with this. Then put someone else mental picture of what css is and what or how internet works in your mind. If you have control from the start of course this is noobish and a thing that will make your life hard in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You forget to apply the class.

```
.courier {
font-family: "courier";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class='courier'>Unsigned Vs Signed Integers</h2>
```

Maybe this help.

```
.courier {
    font-family: "courier" !important;  //Incase if any css conflict occurs
    }
```

From your comments, try this

```
* { font-family: "courier" !important; }. There may be css conflict
```

> `*` represent all HTML elements.
>
> `! important` like absolute, never get changed.

Also check whether for any similar CSS, if you found anything similar to this remove !important.

Comment: doing this worked for the heading, however how can I make it work for all other text? I tried using * as Joseph Myers mentioned but it didn't work.

Comment: The reason this works, but only for the `h2` element is because the class rule is more specific than the `*` rule. There must be another rule in your CSS somewhere else that is setting the font, which has a priority somewhere inbetween the `*` selector and the class selector.

Comment: `* {
    font-family: courier;
  }` represent all html attribute.  **so may this help `* {
    font-family: "courier" !important;
  }`.  There may be css conflict**

Comment: If there's a CSS rule conflict, the far better solution is to find and remove the conflict, not shout over it with `!important`.

Comment: @cHao Yup I accept 99%.  I was also thinking out this.  What happens, if they have applied the `!important` in both the stylesheet.  We have to follow standard way of writing CSS, but this is just an immediate workaround solution.  That is the reason I mentioned check for conflict and remove it.

Comment: If you have icons as a font this is going to be a really big mess.